# Assignment files do not get deleted via course reset after cron execution in Moodle

Tags: cron, moodle

When I try to reset the assignments of a course, front-end wise all data get deleted. I tested this with a single file upload by myself in a test assignment. But when checking disk usage with

```sh
du moodledata/filedir
```

the same usage remains. I ensured execution of the cron task which printed

```
...
Cron script completed correctly
Cron completed at 17:40:03. Memory used 32.8MB.
Execution took 0.810698 seconds
```

The files also are not in moodledata/trashdir probably reason why the cron task does not clean it.

Removing file with

```sh
moosh file-hash-delete <hash>
```

seemed to work. I identified the hash with pre/after executing disk usage and checking hash in the folder that used up the size of the file I uploaded.

The hash was not in the mdl_files table in MySQL, but the draft of it was. This one I found out via

```sh
moosh file-check
```

and I also checked it with phpMyAdmin, which outputted the file(draft) alongside other files.

Logs for resetting the course show the following:

```
Core System, course reset finished, The reset of the course with id '4' has ended.
Core System, deadline updated, The user with id '2' updated the event 'test ist zur Bewertung fällig.' with id '4'.
Core System, deadline updated, The user with id '2' updated the event 'test ist fällig.' with id '3'.
Core System, course reset begin, The user with id '2' started the reset of the course with id '4'.
```

(note that I translated some of the messages, because my setup is in German).

Unfortunately I'm having to run this Moodle instance on a hoster with extremely low disk storage (hence backup/deletion requirement).

Some background infos:

Moodle - version 3.8.2+ stable, dbtype set to mariadb

MariaDB - version 10.3.19

Machine: CentOS Linux 7

UPDATE: It seems that after some days (I checked today, ~4 days later) the files have been deleted. I don't know why this happened after so many days even though I manually triggered the cron job (seems that it doesn't delete the files). It would be nice to check where the timer is set and which script finally deletes the files.

Comment: In the interim, could you host attach some more storage to this compute instance, so you can tackle the problem without haste?

Comment: Unfortunately not but for the time being, 10 GB should be enough for simple assignments and lightweight courses. This hoster has a rather unique business model where you pay as much as you want but anyone gets the "same" service.

Answer (score 0):

On the course reset page, if you scroll down, there is a drop down for **Assignments**

Did you check the box for **Delete all submissions** ?

[image: assignments delete all submissions]

In the code, `$data->reset_assign_submissions` will delete the files:

```
public function reset_userdata($data) {
    global $CFG, $DB;

    $componentstr = get_string('modulenameplural', 'assign');
    $status = array();

    $fs = get_file_storage();
    if (!empty($data->reset_assign_submissions)) {
```

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this and only this. Are there any logs to check if the snippet `$data->reset_assign_submissions` executed correctly? This is a fresh installation of Moodle, by the way